# Need help in converting trigger to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need help in converting my Oracle trigger to T-SQL. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
CREATE TRIGGER "REQUESTOR_TRG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON REQUESTOR 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT REQUESTOR_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
```

I am getting these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure REQUESTOR_TRG, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'BEFORE'
>
> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure REQUESTOR_TRG, Line 7
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a  context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure REQUESTOR_TRG, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near ':'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure REQUESTOR_TRG, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near 'COLUMN_SEQUENCES'.

Comment: What's the goal of the trigger?

Comment: In TSQL you don t have a Before on trigger, do you really need a  before or you can use and after insert? What do you use this trigger for as I can see you are not inserting anything. Is it just to get the ID of a new row?

Comment: yes @ClaudioCorchez

Comment: I have given the table below

Comment: @dineshbalajibingo In Tsql you dont need a trigger to generate an id. You can just set the column as identity column and the DB will do the rest.

Comment: Or even stick with a syntax, and use `default (next value for the-sequence)` in you table definition.